# Delete a pattern that is in a list from inside a string in Python

Tags: python

Well, I have a string:

```
string ="01. 01 22 3 456 0001 02 . 002 3. 0003 4 . 0004 05- 0005 06 - 0006 7- 0007 8 - 0008 09. 0009 10. 0010"
```

And as you see it is a list. The important is just the number/numbers after the dot or hifen. And each number or group of numbers have to become an item in a list like that:

```
["01", "22", "3", "456", "0001", "002", "0003", "0004"....etc]
```

I worked something around regular expressions and I got this list :

```
['01.', '02 .', '3.', '4 .', '09.', '10.', '05-', '06 -', '7-', '8 -']
```

Now I need to remove it from there.
The fist is type str and the second is type list, I coudn't figure out which method to use to solve it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there always a space after the dot/hyphen?

Comment: Yes @wwii, there is always a space right after dot/hifen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
string ="01. 01 22 3 456 0001 02 . 002 3. 0003 4 . 0004 05- 0005 06 - 0006 7- 0007 8 - 0008 09. 0009 10. 0010"
results = re.findall('(?<=\s)\d+(?=\s[\d$])|(?<=\s)\d+(?=$)', string)
```

Output:

```
['01', '22', '3', '456', '0001', '002', '0003', '0004', '0005', '0006', '0007', '0008', '0009', '0010']
```

Comment: Very good, but I revised the question. It may be 1 number or more -after- dot or hifen.

Comment: @samu101108 Then just `\d+`

Comment: @Ajax1234 That's it! Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: `...[\d$]` was the `$` supposed to match the end of the string? --> `...[\d]|$`

Comment: @wwii Yes, although I realized that it needed to be a separate condition in the regex.